# How to filter out all objects from type?

Tags: typescript

I have a type, FilteredType, which looks like this:

```
type ArrayKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Array<any> ? K : never }[keyof T];

interface MyInterface {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: string;
    d: string[];
    e: number[];
    f: { // How can I filter out 'object' properties such as this in addition to arrays?
        g: number;
        h: string;
    }
}

type FilteredType = Omit<MyInterface, ArrayKeys<MyInterface>>;
```

In addition to filtering out arrays, I want to filter out complex object properties such as 'f'. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to reverse your logic to keep only "primitive" values, it would solve itself. See `KeysOfPrimitive` you can extend it further to allow only specified types `KeysOfSpecified`.

```
type primitives = null | undefined | string | number | symbol | boolean | bigint;
type KeysOfPrimitive<T extends Record<any, any>> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends primitives ? K : never }[keyof T];
type KeysOfSpecified<T extends Record<any, any>, ToKeep> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends ToKeep ? K : never }[keyof T];

interface MyInterface {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: string;
    d: string[];
    e: number[];
    f: {
        g: number;
        h: string;
    }
}

type T1 = Pick<MyInterface, KeysOfPrimitive<MyInterface>>;
type T2 = Pick<MyInterface, KeysOfSpecified<MyInterface, string>>;
type T3 = Pick<MyInterface, KeysOfSpecified<MyInterface, number[]>>;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBGBOCWBbex4DcIGcoF4qeAQDsBzKAHyiIFdEAjCWC-EegewBtm63OIBDIt3gl4RYAG4AsAChQkKAGkIITAHkAZgAUEyVBgA8AFSgQAHsAhEAJtgBKEAMZtY1g4JAAaKB4B8v3CgAbygAbUUoMSgAaxU2DSgjAF0ALkTwpNMLK1sYXRR0LCgAfiUoNKIIDCYAX1DYkHjEpOk5cGhlVU0AZUhHeA14CDcTc0sbeycXNw9vP28jNmUIMAC8EPDIoQam5LSjDKzx3MXlsBKyiqrGKDqdhOTW2TFLWA1%20R2gAWRAASXFGO9PsFZFAwT4KrQGLBWuCoHQ0gRiCRYeDHIjCGIUaDwdYMcjQi0cWCIJD6IxCaiwRo0iEAPR0qAACTYAHcoI5BFBflBBhxXlA2NRgFAAORsOgAKycwFFeTYkFgqCKmGojgAFj5sMB1fBsFF%20NZrAU2EJgGwfLBYPxVMViXCoCQydCqQ71fisa6arJvTJZPJoEYAIyBLTwRzRAw-f6vIEQbyddTafL6CBRv4At4fCD%20VoBxIAJlD4cj0czcYTKiTvScAyGbjLsez3iRWNz-vaiQAzMWI%20mY4Dm0oqz0%20nXhv3y0OaOTYITc0A)

Comment: amazing! thanks! :D

Comment: What about `undefined` and `null`?  Are you not using `--strictNullChecks`?

Comment: @jcalz simply forgot...

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are objects, so you can filter using [the `object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type) which specifically means "anything not a primitive":

```
type ObjectKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? K : never }[keyof T];
    
type FilteredType = Omit<MyInterface, ObjectKeys<MyInterface>>;
/* type FilteredType = {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: string;
} */
```

(If you are using [ESLint's ban-types rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md) and it complains about `object`, you should reconfigure it to not complain. There is [nothing wrong with using `object` in this context](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732#issuecomment-886221640).)

---

Note also that if you're using `Omit` to filter keys based on some type function, you can do it in a single type function via [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as):

```
type OmitObjectKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends object ? never : K]: T[K] }

type FilteredType2 = OmitObjectKeys<MyInterface>
/* type FilteredType2 = {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: string;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AaQiAzgHgCoB8UAvFAN5QDaaUAlgHZQDWmA9gGZR4C6AXF9W5QIAD2AR6AEyxRWiFMCgB+KDX70IANwgAnKAF9KLEBy7cA3AFgAUDYbid7AIbJoAWRABJeg+evyNlBQTuoArgC2cLpW1kFw-FjAOgwA5jFByAlJqelQklnJ9CmUFoHCYZG6Jbns-GRlQSkVUTq5QQAWBTll+ja9ttagkFAAYrQANg4Qknjg0KQw4bTAOB7evi4QADSw8qgY2KtePrp+EAQEMQD0AFRQQ9Bjk7rTs8Ok9bFBwc3RDVDxKCJQppf6ZIHZIoxfRQG5XGw2B6wJbAeBIfaYXCEEjkKg0BjMNicPDBGR4QTCMQSaSyPaKFQabR6fhoPgCVkGBGDOajCZTGZzABMOMWyzRCgOuDWJ0cmwINlu9x5T35bwgwo+-xCUHoERabQBXShYKNoOsMLhNiAA)